# How to securely access a machine using PowerShell remoting over the Internet?

Tags: powershell, winrm, self-signed-certificate, remoting

I have an Azure VM where PowerShell remoting is enabled and WinRM has the HTTPS listener configured to use a self-signed certificate. I can launch some commands on the VM from another machine on the other side of the Internet using PowerShell:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$option = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck
$psSession = New-PSSession -UseSSL -ComputerName $vmHostName -SessionOption $option -Credential $cred
Invoke-Command -Session $psSession -ScriptBlock { Write-Host $env:COMPUTERNAME }
```

I read [how WinRM works from the security point of view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/winrmsecurity). The connection to the VM is protected from passive attackers (confidentiality) and even some active ones (integrity). Still, protection against MitM (authenticity) is missing due to ignoring the CA that signed the cert.

I tried to find an option to pin the cert's thumbprint on the client side, but I found just the `-SkipCACheck`. To my knowledge, `winrs` does not have even that much. I am considering installing the self-signed cert in Cert:\LocalMachine\Root on the client machine to make it trusted but that may be harder on my company's DevOps Server agents, which are not managed by my team and are shared with other teams.

I see tutorials using self-signed cert and `-SkipCACheck` [all](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/connect-winrm) [over](https://docs.vmware.com/en/vRealize-Orchestrator/8.11/com.vmware.vrealize.orchestrator-use-plugins.doc/GUID-2F7DA33F-E427-4B22-8946-03793C05A097.html) the place. There are just a few ones that [do not use a self-signed cert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/system-management-components/configure-winrm-for-https). I wonder why such an insecure setup is demonstrated without warning and hints on securing it. Even here on Server Fault, my confusion is [not unique](https://serverfault.com/q/677815/197218).

How should I proceed when I need to connect to the VM over the public Internet? Is there a secure way to use a self-signed cert with WinRM? Is there a simple way to get a trusted certificate for the WinRM lister on the machine?

Comment: Found an article on setting up [WinRM auth using client certs](https://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/certificate-password-less-based-authentication-in-winrm). Seems like this may be the way to go. More cumbersome than password and pinned thumbprint, though. :-(

Comment: `Seems like this may be the way to go.` that convoluted mess is what you are looking for? Instead of using the free CA provided by the vendor that is easy to configure and manage?

Comment: Which vendor do you mean, @GregAskew? CAs supporting ACME? The important context is that I need to make this work for exactly one Azure VM where my team deploys from a bunch of DevOps agents owned by a different team. The convoluted mess will likely need to be configured once on the VM and once scripted as part of the DevOps pipeline. But maybe I did not read deep enough into the article -- found it not long before midnight local time. We already have WinACME on the VM to provide certs to the app's domains. Is using it to provide a trustworthy cert to the VM's primary domain possible?

Comment: From the perspective of practitioners of this forum, this is a kludge. It ignores existing free, native technology provided by the vendor that is simple and easy to configure and administer, is a config management surprise that will probably get passed around like uranium due to no one wants to be anywhere near it.

Comment: What is that free, native technology provided by the vendor, @GregAskew? Likely, this is the part of the puzzle that I am missing. I will happily accept "just don't, do this instead" as an answer.

Comment: I reformulated the question to better express my intent and incorporate some research I've done. I do not care about using self-signed certs specifically -- I care about the security of access to the VM. I also added an answer describing the solution I am currently using.

Comment: Self-signed certificates are a way of bypassing security. It's the equivalent of saying "this isn't a real/important system, let's insert a placeholder where the"security" "option" would be. While there may be legitimate uses for them, using them on a production system is not. Most of the "value" in certificates is a concept known as trust. Using a certificate implies that you trust the issuer 100% to safeguard the information and many other things. With self signed certificates this concept does not exist, and therefore can never be equivalent to a real certificate.

Comment: Self-signed certificates are e.g. the root certificates of CAs. The trust is usually expressed by placing such certs into the trust store, and anything signed by such a cert is trusted, including other certs, transitively. [Pinning](https://owasp.org/www-community/controls/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning) further improves the security (OWASP explains how). When all the clients pin the cert (as in my case), there is no need for any other mechanism to establish trust. The reason a pinned self-signed cert cannot be used here is that the tooling around WinRM does not support pinning.

Comment: Regardless, I agree that using PKI over pinned self-signed certs provides many benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a trusted certificate instead of the self-signed one.

Using the ACME protocol with one of the free CAs (Let's Encrypt, ZeroSSL, Buypass Go SSL) is simple and secure. [WinACME](https://www.win-acme.com/) is an ACME client for Windows, which is simple to configure and has all that is needed to set up and maintain the certificate.

As the certificate installation step in WinACME, i.e. the step that runs after the cert is issued/renewed, use the [script plugin](https://www.win-acme.com/reference/plugins/installation/script) with `Scripts\ImportWinRM.ps1` in the directory where WinACME is installed and pass `{CertThumbprint}` (literally) as its parameters list. The script:

1. finds the cert in Cert:\LocalMachine using the thumbprint,
2. copies the cert to Cert:\LocalMachine\My unless it is already there,
3. looks up the WinRM listener based on the matching hostname,
4. reconfigures the listener to use the cert, and
5. restarts the WinRM service.

Once the WinRM listener uses the trusted certificate, do not forget to drop `-SkipCACheck` on the client.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$psSession = New-PSSession -UseSSL -ComputerName $vmHostName -Credential $cred
Invoke-Command -Session $psSession -ScriptBlock { Write-Host $env:COMPUTERNAME }
```